# My Jquery not working with displaying the divs in the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, hide, show

My Jquery code looks to be written correct, but it's still not working.

```js
$('#nextBtn1').click(function() {
  $('#jobSetupPage1').hide();
  $('#jobSetupPage2').show();
});

$('#nextBtn2').click(function() {
  $('#jobSetupPage2').hide();
  $('#jobSetupPage1').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="jobSetup1" id="jobSetupPage1">
  <div class="container" id="jobName">
    <div class="title" id="jobNameTitle">Job name:</div>
    <input type="text" name="jobNameValue" id="jobNameValue">
    <img src="icons/arrow_right_60x60_wh.png" class="icons nextBtn" id="nextBtn1">
  </div>

  <div class="jobSetup2" style="display: none;" id="jobSetupPage2">
    <img src="icons/arrow_left_60x60_wh.png" class="icons prevBtn" id="prevBtn2">
  </div>
```

Comment: define **still not working**

Comment: There's no element with id `nextBtn2` in your html. Did you mean `prevBtn2`?

Comment: I tried similar code in W3Scools, and it works perfect, tried on my code, no answer from the server

Comment: yes, there is _prevBtn2_

Comment: what answer for the server? i don't see any ajax calls or any other type of request

Answer (score 2):

Its because page 2 is a child of page 1. You correctly need to define the HTML to avoid such unexpected bugs.

Plus, there is no element with the ID `nextBtn2` in your HTML.

```js
$('#nextBtn1').click(function() {
  $('#jobSetupPage1').hide();
  $('#jobSetupPage2').show();
});

$('#prevBtn2').click(function() {
  $('#jobSetupPage2').hide();
  $('#jobSetupPage1').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="jobSetup1" id="jobSetupPage1">
  <div class="container" id="jobName">
    <div class="title" id="jobNameTitle">Job name:</div>
    <input type="text" name="jobNameValue" id="jobNameValue">
    <img src="icons/arrow_right_60x60_wh.png" class="icons nextBtn" id="nextBtn1"> page 1
  </div>
</div><!-- close div here -->

<div class="jobSetup2" style="display: none;" id="jobSetupPage2">
  <img src="icons/arrow_left_60x60_wh.png" class="icons prevBtn" id="prevBtn2"> page 2
</div>
```

Comment: <img src="icons/user_60x60_wh.png" class="icons" value="0" id="user">

<div class="container" id="loginPage" style="display: none;">
<form id="loginForm">
</form>
</div>

$('document').ready(function functionName() {
    $('#user').click(function () {
        $('#loginPage').toggle();
    });
});
This one works well

Comment: I have a different button which toggles a window, and it works. Did the same way with prev/next buttons, but nothing happens

Comment: @MaximRoman Please do not post code in comments - especially not without telling what it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

You have some div closing problems with `jobSetupPage1` you need to close it before the `jobSetupPage2` and you have the wrong selector for your second click event, should be `#prevBtn2`

```js
$('#nextBtn1').click(function() {
  $('#jobSetupPage1').hide();
  $('#jobSetupPage2').show();
});

$('#prevBtn2').click(function() {
  $('#jobSetupPage2').hide();
  $('#jobSetupPage1').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="jobSetup1" id="jobSetupPage1">
  <div class="container" id="jobName">
    <div class="title" id="jobNameTitle">Job name:</div>
    <input type="text" name="jobNameValue" id="jobNameValue">
    <img src="icons/arrow_right_60x60_wh.png" class="icons nextBtn" id="nextBtn1">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="jobSetup2" style="display: none;" id="jobSetupPage2">
  page2
  <img src="icons/arrow_left_60x60_wh.png" class="icons prevBtn" id="prevBtn2">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

I put the jQuery function inside:-

```
$('document').ready(function() {});
```

and it is working now.

Comment: How can it be possible, when your selector as well as html  is wrong

Comment: still if the selecore is wrong code will not work (button selector)